# Removing Katoolin from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, software-uninstall, katoolin

I made the mistake of installing Katoolin package https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin. The problem is it botched up my Ubuntu, many packages don't work anymore. System update doesn't work anymore.

**The question: is there a way to somehow uninstall this from my Ubuntu without re-installing the OS??**

PS: Piece of advice to people who want to study computer security: stay away from this Katoolin tool! Think at least ten times before installing it.

Comment: If, as you've said, "many packages don't work anymore", then uninstalling will not solve the problems. You might need to backup and then do a clean install.

Comment: Start with steps in my answer. In point (4), add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Answer in progress

1. Run the Python script in `/usr/bin/katoolin` again

   ```
   sudo /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
2. Select `1) Add Kali repositories & Update`
3. Select `3) Remove all kali linux repositories`
4. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -f
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
5. Remove the katoolin script

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
6. Run

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/*release
   ```

   Change the file like this (depending on your release):

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04  
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=Xenial Xerus  
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04"
   ```

   Save and close the file.
7. Run

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/*issue
   ```

   Change the file like this (depending on your release):

   ```
   Ubuntu 16.04 \n \l
   ```

   Save and close the file.
8. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have solved some problems with removing packages. Some apps still don't work but this should be solved by uninstalling/installing them individually. I'm pretty sure some other people might find this thread useful. Cheers.