# Ubuntu 16.04 and Katoolin removing failed

Tags: software-center, uninstall, 16.04

Unfortunately, I installed Katoolin by following [these steps](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin). After installation, I tried to remove it using this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708836/removing-katoolin-from-ubuntu-14-04). Now, I  see this weird menu. I can't take screenshot, menu is closed while I take  a screenshot)

[image: worst screenshot and i know it]

So my question is, how can I remove this thing?

And my Software Center doesn't run anymore!

Here it is my output in terminal by running software-center command:

```
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 54, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 176, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], level)
ImportError: No module named kaliile "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 176, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], level)
ImportError: No module named kali
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 54, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 176, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], level)
ImportError: No module named kali
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Katoolin from Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/708836/removing-katoolin-from-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

based on [this solution](https://github.com/LionSec/wifresti/issues/8#issuecomment-177288516) i fix it.
The solution below has fixed my problem:

```
gksu gedit /etc/*release
```

Change the file like this (this is for 15.10 but you can change accordingly)

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Xenial Xerus
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04"
```

save and close the file.

```
gksu gedit /etc/*issue


sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```