# How to procede if all I can have acess is grub2 shell basic?

Tags: grub2, usb, uefi, display-resolution, crash

1. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot. I removed Windows 10. No problems.
2. I installed Katoolin (no problems).
3. After updating Ubuntu and rebooting the system this happened:

**BIOS:**

Kali GNU/LINUX
Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux
UEFI Firmware Settings

If I choose Kali GNU/Linux, only appears the Ubuntu symbol.
If I choose others, it fail to start.
I can't have the privilege to modify anything If I choose the UEFI option.
[image]

[image]

When the recovery mode was working, I use this command:

Ctrl + Alt + F2

```
sudo apt-get reinstall ubuntu
```

Nothing changed.

Then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

I used it to remove Ubuntu and Kali (a stupid mistake). At the time I thought that would be the solution from the boot order.

Comment: I don't know. How to check that?

Comment: Just Ubuntu. Erase disks means delete my all partitions? I can do it from grub2?

Comment: You can format your disks using the "Disks" application in a live session (Try Ubuntu).  Format them using a GPT partition scheme, then reboot into the flash drive (UEFI).  Formatting will erase all data, so watch what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have other computer to make this. Maybe installing Ubuntu in my smartphone and then make this flash drive? (I have one Flash drive with Ubuntu 18.04 mininal, but the system don't recognize)

Comment: I am confused by this.  How did you install Ubuntu without installation media?

Comment: I had one at time.

Comment: @Nmath I think I know what happened. Installing `katoolin` involved adding Kali repositories along with Ubuntu ones. Now OP has a Frankenstein Ubuntu-Kali hybrid OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Katoolin from Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708836/removing-katoolin-from-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Search for `katoolin` in this site. There are some other questions and answers that may be helpful.

Comment: @user68186 Yes, the first error was "etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh: line 2: /usr/bin/locale-check: no such file or directory" in login interface. I removed the Ubuntu-Kali hybrid OS too, soo I had nothing now.

Comment: I have been playing with **EtchDroid** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274361/can-we-use-etchdroid-to-create-ubuntu-installation-media/1274545#1274545, it will let you install Ubuntu to a USB from your phone, (Similar to balenaEtcher). You can also use **DriveDroid** to install Ubuntu directly from your phone, without need of a USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media