# Failed to start processes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, startup

I am having a problem with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 Desktop version on my Studio XPS 1645 with an Intel Core i7 Q720, 6 GB of RAM, and a 250 GB SSD. While booting I'm brought to a screen with the error messages:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Greenbone Vulnerability Manager daemon (gvmd).
[Failed] Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon.
```

This happened after a reset after installing Katoolin3, if this has something to do with it. I'm also new to Linux and do not know what to do. Please help, thank you.

Comment: [Properly removing katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708836/removing-katoolin-from-ubuntu-14-04) will likely solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo systemctl disable gvmd.service
```

and:

```
sudo systemctl stop gvmd.service
```